# AddComponent() not applying Presets

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have made a preset to be applied to a Game Object on a Particular Component. It works fine when I add component through Inspector but when I add Component using Script it is not applying the preset.

[image: Component Preset]

Any Help is Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: by preset you mean the default references? Those are only applied via the Inspector ... If you need to add those on runtime maybe use a prefab?

Comment: No, not Default Reference I mean the Preset Manager Presets for Component.

Comment: Please show the script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I understand the [PresetManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PresetManager.html) as well is a pure editor tool which only applies when adding components via the Inspector or importing assets .. it doesn't mention any runtime or editor script `AddComponent` calls